# stream closed exception in jsp while evaluating  struts2  debug tag?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

i have one struts2 application, working finr. But when i put  tag in jsp in html form or anywhere else, it throws

```
Struts Problem Report
Struts has detected an unhandled exception: 
Messages: Stream closed 
File: org/apache/jasper/runtime/JspWriterImpl.java 
Line number: 204 

Stacktraces
java.io.IOException: Stream closed 
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.ensureOpen(JspWriterImpl.java:204)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:115)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flush(JspWriterImpl.java:173)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary
```

Also i have mentioned `struts.devMode=true` in `struts.properties`.

The basic reason we get this kind of exception is  when output of jsp has already been to browser but some content is still being evaluated   but not sure why it is happening my scenario?

**EDIT** Here is the jsp though i have just kept the minimum information in it

```
<!doctype html>
 <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
 <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

  <html>
 <head>
 </head>

 <body>
 <h1>Struts 2 debug tag example</h1>

 <s:debug />

 </body>
 </html>
```

**Folks would be really helpful if somebody can throw some light on this?**

Comment: Please paste your JSP as well.

Comment: You'll need to provide further information; is it S2 tags *specifically*? Have you tried a JSP with only a *single* S2 tag?

Comment: yes its S2 teag only.struts-tags.tld version is 2.2. I want to debug this specific jsp , so i did not try JSP with only single S2 tag

Comment: also tried with JSP with only single tag but same error. Replacing the new JSP with old one in edit part

Comment: Also attached the compile JSP file. Not getting how stream is getting closed due to s:debug tag